# How to change the default EditText text size

Tags: android

I am trying to change the default `EditText` style, I have done it with the `TextView` style the following way:

```
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize</item>
</style>
```

And using it as the android:textViewStyle style

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

How can I achieve the same with an `EditText` ?

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449169/how-to-change-style-of-a-default-edittext

Comment: @Lokesh it is not what i need

Comment: Then give me brief explanation what you want exactly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just use this code in your Project you can get the required Edittext style throughout your project...

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomEditTextStyle">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/edittxt_shape</item>
<item name="android:clickable">true</item>
<item name="android:enabled">true</item>
<item name="android:focusable">true</item>
<item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

and add this line in your Mainfest file

```
<application
android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

All the best

Comment: Thanks there is only the parent="android:Widget.EditText" missing.

Answer (score 1):

this site may helps you 
try [this](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

> http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 0):

edittext_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#26ADE4" />

        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#26ADE4" />

        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#26ADE4" />

        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

check this custom style

use the following attribute to apply this to your editText

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score 0):

You can custom style by adding this property of  EditTest:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
            android:textColor="@color/pink" />
```

Answer (score 0):

create a style like below

```
<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

and apply it in your Editext view like

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"/>
```