# Why isn't my EditText styled to match my AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-design

I am trying to create an `AlertDialog` with a single text field prompt. Here is the code I am using to create it:

```
final EditText url = new EditText(this);
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK)
  .setTitle(R.string.mirror_title)
  .setView(url)
  .setPositiveButton(...)
  .setNegativeButton(...)
  .show();
```

When I run that against API level 22, the buttons style using Material as expected, but the `EditText` does not:

[image: Dialog with old-style text input]

What do I need to do to get the new style `EditText` here?

Comment: [How to change style of a default EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17449332/1160282) || [Using styles and themes in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17449332/1160282)

Comment: EditText elements I put in a layout are the new style as expected, only this one in the dialog is the old kind. That leads me to believe there something wring with the way I've configured the alert rather than a need to add a custom style to my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault` as your alert dialog theme, but your `EditText` is using whatever theme was set on the `Context` represented by `this`.

To ensure consistency between your alert dialog's decor and contents, you should always create the contents using the alert dialog's themed context.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, ...)
    .setTitle(R.string.mirror_title)
    .setPositiveButton(...)
    .setNegativeButton(...);

Context dialogContext = dialogBuilder.getContext();
EditText url = new EditText(dialogContext);

dialogBuilder.setView(url).show();
```

As a side note, it looks like you may need to specify an activity theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and check that your `targetSdkVersion` is specified correctly. You shouldn't be seeing Gingerbread-styled widgets unless you are explicitly targeting the Gingerbread themes (ex. `Theme` or `Theme.Light`).