# Applying an accent color to an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-theme, android-styles

Is it possible to apply an accent color to an particular EditText while others are unaffected ?

i have this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <!-- EditText on a blue background -->
  <style name="BlueBGTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
  </style>

  <!-- default EditText -->
  <style name="AppTheme.EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
  </style>

  <!-- default Theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item> <!-- use to setup the color of the text selection handles -->   
    <item name="@attr/BlueBGTextViewStyle">@style/BlueBGTextView</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

but the problem is that `<item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item>` is applied globally to all my edits. I would like to apply it only to the

```
<style name="BlueBGTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
</style>
```

any idea how i can do this ?

Comment: use different theme for edittext! it will work

Comment: this might me what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17449169/6904440

Comment: create a theme and use it only with the specific edittext that you are tryiing to customize.

Comment: simo, i don't understand how you can create a them and use it only with the specific EditText, because the theme must be connected in androidmanifest and only one can be connected as i know

Answer (score 1):

try this, i have tested it on my system.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:theme="@style/Edittext" />
```

declare your theme is styles.xml

```
<style name="Edittext" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ed2727</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ed2727</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ed2727</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ed2727</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ed2727</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ed2727</item>

</style>
```

reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Comment: thanks xbadal, but how you do this ? i create my edit via the constructor with a DefStyleAttr

Comment: also i want to apply the accent color to only a particular edit, not all the edit of the application

Comment: unfortunatly it's not work :( note that i create the EditText manually not via xml

Comment: have you created custom Edittext? can you post that class?

Comment: i just create the edittext via it's constructor: EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)

Answer (score 1):

I have used like this hope this can help u

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme">
    <!-- Used for the bottom line when not selected / focused -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#9e9e9e</item>
    <!-- colorControlActivated & colorControlHighlight use the colorAccent color by default -->
</style>
```

Now u can apply this theme to particular edittext

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"/>
```